# ios - Error when hiding button through code Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to hide a button through code, but the program crashes every time I try to hide it.

The error I get:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem setHidden:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14ef8f30'
```

.h file code:

```
@property (strong) UIButton *takeAll;
```

.m code:

```
    @synthesize takeAll;

// function

   [self.takeAll setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: add the code of `takeAll` button allocation

Comment: takeAll is UIBarButtonItem, u probably want to associated the outlet to the button inside this buttonItem.

Comment: For some reason I cant hide it when i declare it as a UIBarButtonItem, how do i fix this?

Comment: Why do you have the `@synthesize` line? That hasn't been needed for many years. You should find an up-to-date Objective-C tutorial.

Comment: New to iOS and working on an older project so i've just been following the format. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is clearly saying **'You are trying to set hidden value of `UIBarButtonItem`**

You created a `UIButton` object and allocation as `UIBarButtonItem`. This is wrong. It suppose to be

```
self.takeAll = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]
```

If you need `UIBarButtonItem` then

```
@property (strong) UIBarButtonItem *takeAll;
```

And if you want hide `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
 self.takeAll.enabled = false
 self.takeAll.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor
```

Enable the bar button item

```
 self.takeAll.enabled = true
 self.takeAll.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor
```

Comment: yeah, sorry didnt think about changing colour to hide it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

UIBarButtonItem does not have a `setHidden:` selector. You may want to set the tint color of the button to a clear color and disable it, which will essentially provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you have subclass of UIView inside UIBarButtonItem you can hide it with this code`

`[barButtonItem.customView setHidden:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

The crash shown is in UIBarButtonItem.
In the interface file the declaration is for a UIButton. May be you are trying to link a UIButton to UIBarButtonItem.